# Get-ChildItem Cert:\ (Locally executed) vs. Invoke-Command results difference confusion?

Tags: powershell

I am working on the code below. I am trying to determine why the result is different, given the script command line is the same.

**Executed Locally from SVRAD1:**

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -ExpiringInDays 365 -Recurse | where-object {$_.subject -like "*Microsoft*"} | Select-Object ThumbPrint, FriendlyName, Subject, NotAfter, HasPrivateKey, Issuer | ogv
```

The result shows 4x SSL Certs:

[image]

**Executed Locally from my laptop against SVRAD1:**

```
$DCList = 'SVRAD1'
Invoke-Command -Computer $DCList {
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -ExpiringInDays 365 -Recurse | where-object {$_.subject -like "*Microsoft*"} | Select-Object ThumbPrint, FriendlyName, Subject, NotAfter, HasPrivateKey, Issuer
} | ogv
```

The result shows only 2x SSL Certs:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the certificate is doubled while running locally as evident from the thumbprint, and this has to do with the current user. Add to your list of objects

```
..., PSPath | ogv
```

or `PSParentPath`. You will see the two duplicates have

```
Certificate:LocalMachine
Certificate:CurrentUser
```

in their base. So, you are seeing the same certificate accessed in two different paths. Of course, when you run remotely the current user certificate will be missing, and you only see the local machine one (local machine is the remote SVRD in this case where the command runs, not your own).

Comment: Ok, so how to get the both LocalMachine only for the remote servers?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer That's what you are getting.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Perhaps I was unclear about the "local machine" thing - local machine is SVRD, the machine in context of the command, not your personal laptop. I have edited in this info.

Comment: many thanks for the updated comments, yes it makes more sense now.